# Find ember validator with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ember.js

I am attempting to write selenium scripts for a site that renders the UI with Ember. I want to be able to assert that an alert is thrown (in this case when the user does not fill out a field and hits a create button).

When I leave the text box empty and click the button an Ember Validator is thrown saying "Please fill out this field." I want to use the Selenium switch.to functionality but I can not find any type of way to find the ember validator!

Does anyone have an example of how to find an Ember Validator with Selenium and assert the text is present?

Thank you.